# Why does this variable have different values in different source files?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

main.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

int main() {
    Create();
}
```

Test.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include "Function.h"

class Test {
public:
    Test();
};

extern Test* g_pTest;

inline void Create() {
    g_pTest = new Test;
    std::cout << "On Test.h: " << std::endl;
    PrintAddr();
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

Test* g_pTest = nullptr;

Test::Test() {
    std::cout << "On Test.cpp:" << std::endl;
    PrintAddr();
}
```

Function.h

```
#pragma once

void PrintAddr();
```

Function.cpp

```
#include "Function.h"
#include "Test.h"

void PrintAddr() {
    std::cout << "g_pTest address is " << g_pTest << std::endl;
}
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

**On Test.cpp:**

**g_pTest address is 0000000000000000**

**On Test.h:**

**g_pTest address is 000002008A5EAE40**

I thought that a extern variable was supposed to have the same value anywhere on the code, so why doesn't it? I've tried to run the same code, but instead of the Test class, I just have a function:

Test.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include "Function.h"

void Test();

extern int* g_pTest;

inline void Create() {
    g_pTest = new int;
    Test();
    std::cout << "On Test.h: " << std::endl;
    PrintAddr();
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

int* g_pTest = nullptr;

void Test() {
    std::cout << "On Test.cpp:" << std::endl;
    PrintAddr();
}
```

And it somehow works if it is done this way, I don't understand the logic...
What am I doing wrong here? What can I do in order to use a class and have access to the same extern variable in any code file?

Comment: `std::cout << "On Test.cpp:" << std::endl;` happens before `g_pTest = new Test;` finishes.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I feel a bit frustated that I didn't notice this by myself, but I also feel a relief that it was something easy to fix :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main() {
    Create();
}
```

`main` calls `Create()`, which does this:

```
    g_pTest = new Test;
```

`Test` gets `new`ed ***first***. `g_pTest` gets assigned ***after*** `Test`'s constructor finishes and the object is constructed.

`Test`'s constructor calls `PrintAddr` which prints the value of `g_pTest` because it is ***still nullptr***:

```
Test* g_pTest = nullptr;
```

This remains the case until ***after*** `Test` finishes constructing.

Only ***after*** the constructor wraps up its business the pointer to the new object gets assigned to `g_pTest`, and then the 2nd call to `printAddr` (from `Create`) prints the value of the pointer, which is now pointing to the new object.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb now... I thought this was related to some weird behaviour with the way I included everything, but it was just this... Thanks for clarifying eveything.